# How to create trigram index on json attribute in cockroachdb?

Tags: cockroachdb

Is there a way to create trigram index on a json attribute in cockroach DB just like normal columns like `CREATE INDEX ON t USING GIN (a, w gin_trgm_ops)`?

Answer (score 0):

Not directly, but there is a workaround to create an expression index where the expression is a expression returning the json attribute.

For example: `CREATE INDEX ON t USING GIN ((json_col->>'json_text_field'))`.

You could find more details on https://www.cockroachlabs.com/docs/stable/trigram-indexes.html#examples